# Login to network location with different userid pwd via C#

Tags: c#, networking, authentication, path, unc

I checked all articles available on internet to find solution but unable to solve this problem so asking for help from our community.

Problem:
I am copying files and integrating them via tool designed in C#.net from a network location which use different username then windows login credentials.

Network Path looks like =  \\company.city.com
User id: differentfrom windows login id

I only have to login to this location once and then it stays logged in until I log off but I want to login via C# code before I copy files everytime.

I tried to use this code but which does not work it give error not sure why may be it consider network path as weblocation.

```
     WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create("\\\\company.city.com");
    \\or WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create("\\\\company.city.com\\folder");
    request.Method = request.Method.Clone;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_id","password");

    WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Which particular line in your code example above fails? What is the error?

Comment: fails on line Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

Comment: even with correct user credentials it says "Access Denied"

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web server or a folder? Looking at the code, I assume this is a folder via a UNC path, and not something served by a web server. If so, your method of trying to attach is as if you were calling a secure web page with a network credential. While they may seem to work the same, authenticating on a network to access a share and throwing network credentials at a web site or web service are completely different functions.

What you need to do is Windows Impersonation, not add credentials to socket communication. That is where I would start my Google journey. I have not dinked around with .NET 4.0, but in prior versions this meant P/Invoke on some native windows library. Once you solve the authentication and authorization issue, grabbing the file will be much easier.

Comment: it gives an error that Access denied even I have right user credentials

Comment: So, if you want to pull the file in a non-programmatic manner, can you get it? or do you still have access denied? If still a problem, there is probably a domain trust issue. If not a problem, then the manner in which you are programming is the core issue, not access. You have to determine that first.

Comment: The issue then is the programmatic direction and trying HTTP security methods will not work for windows authentication. See if this might help (http://blog.shynet.nl/post/2008/08/08/Impersonator.aspx). Interesting little class designed to get files with security context (even impersonate a user that is not present?).